# path to component WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.(..) is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I struggle to use a function of an indirectly imported class.

The **components/SignUpForm component** looks roughly like this and..

```
import React from 'react';
import Firebase from "components/firebase/index"

const submitForm = (event) => { 
        event.preventDefault();
        Firebase.testmest("aaaaaaa");
}
```

.. as you see it imports a component **component/firebase/index.js**.
That **index.js component** has one default export and one named export:

```
import FirebaseContext from 'components/firebase/Context';
import Firebase from 'components/firebase/Firebase';
 
export default Firebase;

export { FirebaseContext };
```

The default export refers to a class **component/firebase/Firebase.js**:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
    };

class Firebase {
    constructor(){
        app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        this.auth = app.auth();
    }

    testmest = (hello) => {
        alert(hello);
    }
}

export default Firebase;
```

Whenever I try calling testmest from the SignUpForm Component as you see in the first code block I get the following error message:

> TypeError: components_firebase_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.testmest is not a function

Comment: why don't you export them both  as :
`import FirebaseContext from 'components/firebase/Context';
import Firebase from 'components/firebase/Firebase';
 
export { FirebaseContext,Firebase };`

Comment: I just did so. However, I am still getting the same error message. What could be the reason?